# ASP.NET controls not recognised in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the

> "The name 'ASP.net control' does not exist in the current context"

Error message. Guys, can you please help me find out the cause of this and how to remedy it!

Am I missing something here??

```
<%@ Page Title="Amatola Water Activities" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="AWActivitiesWeb2.Default" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons behind this error, Looking at the `<%@ Page %>` directive that you shared, you have specified the attribute as `CodeFile="~/Default.aspx.cs"` Which might be causing this issue because if you specify a `CodeFile` attribute, the `designer.cs` file does not regenerates itself. Either you manually specify each control you add into the `designer.cs` file or you should change the `CodeFile` attribute to a `CodeBehind` attribute.

The other issue could be with the control itself, if you won't specify `runat="server"` on the attribute then you won't get its reference in the Code Behind.

So, Modify your page directive with this line:

```
<%@ Page Title="Amatola Water Activities" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="~/Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AWActivitiesWeb2.Default" %>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works fine. Both the issues you pointed out were the cause, mainly the 'runat="server"'... The 'CodeFile/CodeBehind' attribute is tricky because my other apps run without issues regardless which I use.

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure to accept the answer if it solved the problem.